# mapStateToProps not updating when redux store updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm working in a react native app with react redux integration. When I call dispatch from a service my store is getting updated but somehow my component is not re-rendering.

Is it wrong to call dispatch from a service file and not from mapDispatchToProps function.

store.js

```js
import { memesReducer } from './memesReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    memesReducer
});

export default configureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer);
    return store;
}
```

memesReducer.js

```js
const initialState = { memeList: [] }

export const memesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOAD_MEMES: {
                return { ...state,
                    memeList: action.data
                }
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

memeService.js

```js
import configureStore from '../redux/store';
import { loadMemes } from '../redux/actions';

const store = configureStore();

export const getMemesList = () => {
    axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
        .then(response => {=
            store.dispatch(loadMemes(response.data))
        })
        .catch(error => { console.error('getMemesList : ', error); })
}
```

memeActions.js

```js
export const loadMemes = memesListData => ({
    type: LOAD_MEMES,
    data: memesListData
});
```

MemeList.js

```js
class MemeList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getMemesList()
    }

    render() {
        const memeListData = this.props.memeList.map((meme) => <MemeCard meme={meme} />)

        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                  <List>
                    { memeListData }
                  </List>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        memeList: state.memesReducer.memeList,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MemeList);
```

Comment: Practises aside, look closely in `mapStateToProps` - why would you map `state.memesReducer.memeList`? I think it should be `state.memeList`. 

And it would work even if dispatch called from outside a redux-connected component.

Comment: When you suppose it should re-render?

Comment: @Rohit Bhirud check this how to call from componentDidMount https://stackoverflow.com/a/58760409/6544460

Comment: @Rohit Bhirud check that solution and let me know. still if you face problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/58760409/6544460

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar it would re-render as soon as the store is updated for a connected component.

Comment: @HS I meant something else. OP is calling that in did mount hook and what OP is expecting is unsure to me.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar - ok, cool. It seemed you were directing it to me. Using `@` for directing would have avoided it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memeActions.js

```
export const getMemesList = () => dispatch => {
  axios("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums")
    .then(response => dispatch(loadMemes(response.data)))
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("getMemesList : ", error);
    });
};
const loadMemes = memesListData => ({
  type: "LOAD_MEMES",
  data: memesListData
});
```

memeReducer.js

```
case "LOAD_MEMES": {
   return { ...state, memeList: action.data };
 }
```

index.js

```
export default combineReducers({
  memesReducer: memeReducer
});
```

memeList.js

```
class memeList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getMemesList();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.memeList);
    return <div>MemeList</div>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  memeList: state.memesReducer.memeList
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getMemesList }
)(memeList);
```

Comment: Giving me error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.". Do I have to use some sort of async middleware like redux thunk or saga?

Comment: Using redux thunk worked like charm. Thanks. I'll try further if I could get it to work with service functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah bro it wouldn't work. You should call dispatch in a Redux connected component.

What you can do is `await` or attach a `.then` to the Service Call and THEN call the dispatch after the `await` or inside the `.then`.

Comment: `dispatch` actions would work even if called from non redux connected component, given it should have store and dispatch in the scope

Answer (score -1):

call your actions like this then only i will work.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getMemesList()
}
```

for your more clarification check this official documentation [react redux](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch?_sm_au_=iVV35vBTMsDtMN3j)